# Check and hight light weekend in calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery

i got a calendar generated by php

i want to use jQuery to set color for weekend days

my code is

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var year=<?php echo $year; ?>;
    var month=<?php echo $month; ?>;
    var highlight='red,blue';
    var background='#b7b7b5,#d8d5d4,#f8eec4';

    $("#weekend_highlight").on("change", function(e){
      highlight=this.value;
      $("table td .number").each(function(a,b){  
        var current_date=year+"-"+pad(month)+"-"+pad($(this).text());

        var myDate = new Date(current_date);
    var myD = myDate.getDate();

        if(myDate.getDay() == 6 || myDate.getDay() == 0){
           $("table .day .number").css("color",highlight);

       $('td:contains("'+myD+'")').css('background-color', background);
        }
      });

    });

   })
    
  </script>
```

It set color for all days and weekend day background color not corect. Please see picture.

[image: Background color]

my table similar this:

```
    <td class="day">
    <div style="height:25px"><p class="number">1</p></div>
    <div style="height:50px"><textarea rows="2" class="edit"></textarea></div>
</td>
    <td class="day">
    <div style="height:25px"><p class="number">2</p></div>
    <div style="height:50px"><textarea rows="2" class="edit"></textarea></div>
</td>
   ...
    <td class="day">
    <div style="height:25px"><p class="number">7</p></div>
    <div style="height:50px"><textarea rows="2" class="edit"></textarea></div>
</td>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your instruction

```
$("table .day .number").css("color",highlight);
```

will set the color for all the days,
instead your have to set only the current item of your foreach if it fulfill the condition

```
 if(myDate.getDay() == 6 || myDate.getDay() == 0){
           this.css("color",highlight);
        }
```

Comment: Hi @Ismail Diari : Its work. How to set background for cell contain weekend days please.

Comment: you use **background-color**

Comment: i used this : $('td:contains("'+myD+'")').css('background-color', background);  but it set color for some other cell. please check picture i added. thank you!

Comment: try this.parent().css('background-color', background);

Comment: Thank you. It is ok for cell background but textarea background still white color. i set background-color: none for textarea  but it still same. My cell have two div, one for number, one for textarea.

Comment: hi @ismail-diari , i use $(this).parent().parent().children('.edit').css("background-color",background); to set same bgcolor for textarea but it not work. Can you help me?

Comment: @uyenD, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/n09jde5c/) is a dummy example I made to understand how to pick up the right selector from your table (it is  not the most efficient solution I can give to you, but the fast).
Good luck!